# Change colour of like button in tableview cell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am trying to change the color of the like button in my table view cell to red when the users taps on the like button for a specific post. But at the moment when i click like for one post, all the other post like buttons turn red too.

```
 func didTapLike(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let indexPath = getCurrentCellIndexPath(sender) {
        clickedLike = indexPath
       like()
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell
        
        if let indexPath = clickedLike {
            // change like button to red
            let selectedRow = indexPath.row
            cell.HeartButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "heart.fill"), for: .normal)
            cell.HeartButton.tintColor = UIColor.red
            cell.LikeCount.textColor = UIColor.red
            
        }

   }
}
```

Comment: Please do not show code that contains unknowns. Your job is to provide a [mcve]. What is `clickedLike` and exactly how did it get set? You talk of a button tap; what code is triggered by that tap, and how?

Comment: I have update the code to show where clickedLike is from.

Comment: Cells are reused. `cell.LikeCount.textColor` and the other one should be set to "default" in the `else` case.

Comment: i did this but it made no difference---> if let indexPath = clickedLike {
                //change like color
                    cell.HeartButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "heart.fill"), for: .normal)
                    cell.HeartButton.tintColor = UIColor.red
                    cell.LikeCount.textColor = UIColor.red
            } else {
                cell.HeartButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "heart"), for: .normal)
                cell.HeartButton.tintColor = UIColor.black
                cell.LikeCount.textColor = UIColor.black

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand the **principle of reusable cells**. What is happening is the cells that you have liked are being re-used to the cells that you *never* liked in the first place. Thus, it looks as if you liked everything because property of the cells that you never liked never had their properties reset.

The same cell maybe be reused with **the same properties** later on even though you have set its properties at the cellForRowAt function which is why you may see that there's no changes. Thus, you have to **specifically reset its properties every time it is reused**.

This can be done by overriding the `prepareForReuse()`inside the cell and setting the properties to its default values again. For example, you may want to try the following in your `PostTableViewCell`:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        
        //set it all back to the default values (in this case, heart and black color tint)
        self.HeartButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "heart"), for: .normal)
        self.HeartButton.tintColor = UIColor.black
        self.LikeCount.textColor = UIColor.black
        
    }
```